# How to hide background image from UITableView sides if cells are rounded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using custom cells for my tableview. I have used gradient layer with rounded borders as background for cell, due to which tableview's background image is visible at cell's corner(as shown in figure).

[image: Figure]

What can I do to hide these corners?  My code is as follows:

in viewDidLoad, table has been set as:

```
Table.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mac-gray.png"]];
    Table.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    Table.rowHeight = 83;
    Table.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
@try {
  static NSString *cellIdentifier;
//[self adjustHeightOfTableview:tableView];

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MarketWatch_iPhoneCell *cell = (MarketWatch_iPhoneCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
        if (cell == nil)
        {                
            NSString *nibName = @"iPhoneCell";

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (MarketWatch_iPhoneCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [cell addGradient];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

.......
return cell;
}


-(void) addGradient
{
    //adding gradient to cell
    gradLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        (id)[UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:45/255 green:45/255 blue:45/255 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:22/255 green:22/255 blue:22/255 alpha:1.0].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor,
                        nil];
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height -= cellMargin;
    gradLayer.frame = frame;

    gradLayer.cornerRadius = self.layer.cornerRadius;
    gradLayer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    gradLayer.borderColor = defaultColor;

    [self.layer insertSublayer:gradLayer below:self.contentView.layer];

}
```

**EDIT**

I have set a background image for table in order to have an image when user tries to scroll off the **maximum content offset**.

If I try to use `colorwithpatternimage` to repeat my image pattern as suggested by @Viral, that pattern will be visible when I try to scroll off the **maximum content offset**.

So here are my two Questions:

1) Can I hide corners if I have set my background image for table and having cells with rounded corners?

2) If using image is much simpler, then image should be of what size, and how should it be designed so that if user scrolls beyond offset, that pattern is not followed there.

Please someone guide me. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Add two Line at your `UITableView` created.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.opaque = NO;
```

also put `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

**EDITE:**

```
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Still not working. There is no advantage of clearing cell's background color

Comment: @AnumAmin-     tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the following code..

```
Table.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mac-gray.png"]];//Don't use this code..
```

You can use following code. If you want background image then you can set it to `self.view`.

```
Table.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
Table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

You can try it. I think it will be helpful to you..

Comment: I can't set image to self.view since there are many other things along with table.

Answer (score 0):

Set the backgroundView of UITableView to nil. And then set whatever color you want to.

```
_myTableView.backgroundView = nil;
_myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```